# How do I get Talend tDBBulkExec component to accept a text enclosure?

Tags: csv, delimiter, talend

I'm trying to take data from IBM DB2 and dump it into SQL Server via the tDBBulkExec command. I have situations where there is a field that a "comment" where users can enter everything. tDBBulkExec is pretty rigid in it's options for determining the format of the remote file and only has options for the field delimiter and the row delimiter. Is there any way to get it to recognize that a field is comprised of text?

Comment: Did you try using field enclosure? If not try using field enclosure, where you can enclose your comment field in between characters. I wouldn't recommend you to use either " or ' because that will create another problem, try using combination of special characters which you think will not be seen in data like +% or something else

Comment: This particular Talend component doesn't allow any field enclosure. I've discovered the only issue to be that some fields include the field delimited ";" and so I just replace those with an empty string where they exist... not ideal I suppose but to your point, nothing would be perfect if the application allows any characters. There would always be some problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tDBBulkExec doesn't allow for field enclosure. The solution was to use .replaceAll(";","") on fields that allowed or contained the column delimiter.